# why does changing the font of a textarea force this button down?

Tags: css

Just curious as to why this bit of css

```
select, input, textarea, button
{
    font:99% sans-serif;
}
```

forces the 'submit' button below the textarea and off to the bottom lefthand side on [this page](http://hills.ccsf.cc.ca.us/~cbolton/133/hw/2/2/).

Comment: It looks fine on Safari 5, which suggests to me that it's an exploited bug in your browser, I'm betting 20 it's IE.

Comment: it's flock (so chrome engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textarea is too large and it's pushing it back up.

I'd recomment resizing the width of the text area and adding `float:right` to the textarea, `float:left` to the button and `overflow:hidden` to the `<section id="content">`